# Is there a way to require in multiple modules into a file, which is then exported again as a single module?

Tags: reactjs, module, redux, export, require

Currently working with Redux and was wondering if there was a way to require in multiple modules into a single file, which is then exported again as a single module?

For example, in my `actions/bookmark.js` I group all actions related to bookmarks accordingly:

```
module.exports = {
  fetchBookmarkList: () => {
    return {
      type: 'FETCH_LIST'
    }
  },
  fetchBookmark: () => {
    return {
      type: 'FETCH_BOOKMARK'
    }
  }
}
```

Then in my `actions/index.js` file, I require in all groups of actions (which will include bookmark actions as well as others). Then I would like to export the entire file as a single module.

Schematically I had something like this in mind (obviously this code does not work):

`actions/index.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  require('./bookmark');
  require('./tags');
}
```

The reason that I want to do this is so that I only have to import a single action file that contains all my actions (i.e. the `actions/index.js` file):

Example component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as actions from '../actions';

class BookmarkList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.props.fetchBookmarkList();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div></div>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(null, actions)(BookmarkList);
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that you es6 modules syntax in components then, why not in your redux files?

```
export const fetchBookmarkList = () => {
  return {
    type: 'FETCH_LIST'
  }
};

export const fetchBookmark = () => {
  return {
    type: 'FETCH_BOOKMARK'
  }
}
```

Based on [this reference](http://2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html#re-exporting) I think it could be possible to re-export everything like this:

```
export * from './bookmark'
export * from './tags;
```

But haven't tried it and I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I would **NOT** recommend you to pass all the actions to mapDispatchToProps, only the actions needed by your component

But you could just use in `actions/index.js`:

Using the spread operator:

```
module.exports = {
  ...require('./bookmark');
  ...require('./tags');
}
```

And in ES6 syntax:

`actions/index.js`:

```
export * from './bookmark'
export * from './tags'
```

Comment: The spread operator version doesn't seem to work, but the ES6 version does. THanks!